# Why is my if else statements not working and outputting the right index from an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement

This code is supposed to output the right color from the user's input. The user's input is stored in an array. However, the else statements are not executing/working.

```
string eyecolor;
string colorcin[4];

void color() {
  cout << "I am going to ask you for 4 colors." << endl;
  for (int a = 0; a < 4; a++) {
    cout << "Color " << a + 1 << ": ";
    cin >> colorcin[a];
  }
}

void eyes() {
  cout << "What color are your eyes? ";
  cin >> eyecolor;
  if (eyecolor == "blue" || "Blue" || "green" || "Green" || "hazel" ||
      "Hazel") {
    cout << "Your favorite color is " << colorcin[0] << endl;
  } else {
    cout << "Your favorite color is " << colorcin[1] << endl;
  }
}

int main() {
  color();
  eyes();
}
```

Comment: Provide a more detailed reproduction info: steps to reproduce, expected and actual output.

Comment: @Xeverous I think the question is clear, he's asking why the `else` statement is not executing.  And from the code he has provided, the answer is also pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

This is not how you compare multiple values:

```
if (eyecolor == "blue" || "Blue" || "green" || "Green" || "hazel" ||
      "Hazel") {
```

What this actually does is first compare `eyecolor` with `"blue"`.  If this is false, then `"Blue"` is evaluated in a boolean context.  Because it is a string constant, it decays to a pointer to its first element, and because that pointer cannot be `NULL`, it evaluates to true, so this expression will always be true.

You need to explicitly compare `eyecolor` with each possible value:

```
if (eyecolor == "blue" || eyecolor == "Blue" || eyecolor == "green" || 
    eyecolor == "Green" || eyecolor == "hazel" || eyecolor == "Hazel") {
```

And the same for `haircolor`.

Answer (score 2):

You have not specified your boolean expressions correctly. For instance, you wrote:

```
if (haircolor == "blond" || "Blond" || "Red" || "red" || "Auburn" || "auburn")
```

This should be:

```
if (haircolor == "blond" || haircolor == "Blond" || haircolor == "Red"
        || haircolor == "red" || haircolor == "Auburn" || haircolor == "auburn")
```

A literal character array such as "Blond" will be implicitly converted to a boolean true value.

Answer (score 1):

do you mean `hair();` function?
its working fine
see

```
Pick a number betweem 1-100: 1                                                                                                
Pick another number between 1-100: 2                                                                                          
I am going to ask you for 4 colors.                                                                                           
Color 1: 1                                                                                                                    
Color 2: 2                                                                                                                    
Color 3: 3                                                                                                                    
Color 4: 4                                                                                                                    
What color is your hair? blond                                                                                  
Your favorite color is 3                                                                                                      
Have a nice day.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, a lot of the answers explain why your approach isn't correct in C++, but nobody has yet provided a solution that solves this cumbersome problem of repeating one variable multiple times.

That being said, I won't cover the details of what is wrong in your code, instead, I will provide you with my solution that makes things a lot easier in cases where you need to use this construct often:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t TSize>
struct AnyOfThis { T values[TSize]; };

template <typename TFirst, typename... TOthers>
auto anyOf(TFirst&& first, TOthers&&... others) {
    return AnyOfThis<std::decay_t<TFirst>, 1 + sizeof...(others)>{std::forward<TFirst>(first), std::forward<TOthers>(others)...};
}

template <typename T, std::size_t TSize>
bool operator==(const T value, const AnyOfThis<typename std::decay<T>::type, TSize>& anyOfThis) {
    return std::find(std::begin(anyOfThis.values), std::end(anyOfThis.values), value) != std::end(anyOfThis.values);
}
```

Basically, it creates a static array from a variadic function. Then there is another function which serves as a comparator, which takes the value you want to compare and looks for this value in the array.

The use-case reads fairly well, too:

```
if (1 == anyOf(1, 2, 3)) {
    // do stuff
}
```

And as you can see in the demo below, with one additional code sugar, you can also put string literals into the `anyOf` function and it will automatically convert them to `std::string` so you can compare them like this:

```
std::string eyecolor("blue");
if (eyecolor == anyOf("blue", "green", "brown")) {
    // do stuff
}
```

---

<kbd>[LIVE DEMO](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6945d8b21f567c23)</kbd>